# Where did Jake Chambers come from?

Tags: the-dark-tower

I recently ended reading *The Dark Tower* series, and I got a doubt. Warning for spoilers of several books.

---

It is stated that the one that dies in the key world is permanently dead and cannot wake up in another reality. In the first book, *The Gunslinger*

> Jake Chambers, the boy companion of Roland arrives in the MidWorld after he was murdered in his home world.

In the second book, *The Drawing of the Three*, we find out that the man that killed

> Jake

was the same that threw a brick on Susannah's head when she was a child and the same that pushed her in the rails when she was young. So, to me,

> Jake

and Susannah came from the same world. Eddie didn't came from their world because in his reality Co-Op city is in Brooklin, but in the real world is in Bronx.

We know that Susannah came from the key world because Moses Carver, her godfather, was the last of Tet Corp. alive when Rolland went to the key world for the last time. And he missed Susannah, that has disappeared in that world.

The question is, Jake was really from the Key World? And if yes,

> why he didn't die permanently when he was pushed in the street and was run over in the first book?

Comment: I've tried to make this a bit easier to read without everything being hidden behind spoiler tags. I haven't read the series so if something is a spoiler but uncovered please feel free to put it inside of spoiler markdown again.

Comment: Pfft, Jake's death isn't a spoiler at all - it happened *before* the series sterted and he *got better*. I also don't see much point in this analysis - if King bothered with such stuff there wouldn't be much *larger* plot holes.